# Get number of matching ng-if of a ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ng-if

Let's say I have something like that :

```
<md-grid-tile class="gray" ng-repeat="carto in cartoList" ng-if="search(carto)">
         <md-button ng-click="changeSVG(carto.fileName)" aria-label="carto.displayName">
             <img src="style/images/thumbnails/{{carto.fileName}}.png" width="100%" height="100%" title="{{carto.fullDisplayName}}" style="max-height: 220px;"></img>
         </md-button>
         <md-grid-tile-footer><h3 align="center">{{carto.displayName}}</h3> </md-grid-tile-footer>
</md-grid-tile>
```

Is there a way to retrieve the number of displayed tiles ? Meaning the number of elements in the `ng-repeat` matching the `ng-if` :

`<md-grid-tile class="gray" ng-repeat="carto in cartoList" ng-if="search(carto)">`

As requested, the `search` function :

```
    $scope.search = function (carto) {
    if ($scope.sideMenu) {
        var searchRegex = new RegExp('global', 'i');

        if (carto.fullDisplayName.search(searchRegex) != -1)
            return true;
    }
    else if ($scope.sideSearch) {
        if ($scope.searched.IS.indexOf(carto.informationSystem) === -1 && carto.informationSystem)
            return false;
        if ($scope.searched.area.indexOf(carto.area) === -1 && carto.area)
            return false;
        if ($scope.searched.block.indexOf(carto.block) === -1 && carto.block)
            return false;
        if ($scope.searched.type.indexOf(carto.type) === -1 && carto.type)
            return false;
        if ($scope.searched.level.indexOf(carto.level) === -1 && carto.level)
            return false;

        if ($scope.searchInput) {
            var searchRegex = new RegExp($scope.searchInput, 'i');

            if (carto.fullDisplayName.search(searchRegex) === -1)
                return false;
        }
        if (!$scope.homeVisible) {
            $scope.homeVisible = true;
            window.history.pushState("newUrl", "CartoViewer", window.location.origin + window.location.pathname);
        }
        return true;
    }
    else
        return true;
};
```

Comment: implement a counter in search function.

Comment: *number of displayed tiles* is just `cartoList.length`. Each iteration's index can be found using `$index`

Comment: @RGraham :`cartoList.length` is the number of tiles (total : diplayed and hidden, including those who dont match my `ng-if`)
@Rohit Kumar :`Implementing a counter in my `search` function, doesn't suit me since it goes through several loops for different filters and return `true` several times for the same `carto`

Comment: @Ellone Can you provide `search(carto)` code from the controller?

Comment: @Ellone I see what you mean now. This seems like an odd pattern. Why are your items even in `cartoList` if they're not going to be shown? Seems like `search()` should happen outside the `ng-repeat` leaving you with only the items you need and not having to `ng-if` each individual item

Comment: @RGraham `cartoList` is generated from a JSON file, and each `carto` is an object with different fields.
The user can then specify which `carto` is displayed using search input and filtering checkboxes.

Comment: @Alberto I.N.J. : See edit in order to find `search` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I would filter `cartoList` *before* you send it to the view:

```
$scope.cartoListFiltered = function() {
    return $scope.cartoList.filter($scope.search);
};
```

And in your view:

```
<md-grid-tile class="gray" ng-repeat="carto in cartoListFiltered()">
         <md-button ng-click="changeSVG(carto.fileName)" aria-label="carto.displayName">
             <img src="style/images/thumbnails/{{carto.fileName}}.png" width="100%" height="100%" title="{{carto.fullDisplayName}}" style="max-height: 220px;"></img>
         </md-button>
         <md-grid-tile-footer><h3 align="center">{{carto.displayName}}</h3> </md-grid-tile-footer>
</md-grid-tile>
```

This runs your `$scope.search` against each individual `carto` and includes only the `carto` which return true. Same as `ng-if` except the logic is executed at the controller (where it should be)

Comment: Not sure I understand how this function can be used as the container of `ng-repeat`.

My search function takes only one element of `cartoList` as parameter and returns true if it matches the search depending on the different search parameters that can be modified in the view.

Comment: @Ellone `filter` executes `search` once per element in `cartoList` - just the same as `ng-if` did. The only difference being you'll have an array of `carto` where only the criteria is matched

Comment: Didn't see your edit, it look alright now.
The number of displayed (matching) element is then `{{cartoListFiltered().length}}` right ?